# Why does gif Image In UITabBarItem on iOS 13 show blue color?

Tags: ios, ios13, uitabbaritem

Why does this **.gif** Image In `UItabbarItem` on `iOS 13` show blue color?

`tabBarItem.selectedImage` is **.gif** image.

`viewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage` = `gifImage`.

The gif image on iOS 13 looks blue color. (Maybe is iOS image default render color)

The gif image on iOS 12 is well.

**How to resolve this on iOS 13?**

Comment: A lot depends on how `sd_animatedGIFWithData` works. But you did not show that code.

Comment: Have you tried checking your storyboard/xib to see if there isnt a default tint?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely SDWebImage library is at fault here. You can try to update it to the newest version and if this doesn't help you need to use something else to load animated gif. I was able do do it with success with help of this [file](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift/blob/master/GIF-Swift/iOSDevCenters%2BGIF.swift).

Just removed

```
import ImageIO
```

line and removed compiler errors with optionals (used suggested fixes).
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is GIF animated or static?

My first bet would be to make it 1 frame only by using:

```c
+ (nullable UIImage *)sd_imageWithData:(nullable NSData *)data
                                 scale:(CGFloat)scale
                        firstFrameOnly:(BOOL)firstFrameOnly;
```

Sources worth checking:

- https://sdwebimage.github.io/SDWebImage/Categories/UIImage%28GIF%29.html
- https://sdwebimage.github.io/SDWebImage/Categories/UIImage%28MultiFormat%29.html#/c:objc(cs)UIImage(cm)sd_imageWithData:scale:firstFrameOnly: